# Is it possible to render local variable multiple times by using res.render

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have a question regard res.render. I am trying to build a very simple messaging feature for my website, not live chat more like Personal Messages, Dms, etc. I am using handlebars to render the html and node.js.

```
app.get('/dashboard/messages/',ensureAuthenticated,function(req,res) {
  res.render('messages');
  Msg.find({ username: req.user.username }, 'username message sender', function (err, msg) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('notfound')
      return handleError(err);

    } else{
      var msgSender = []

      msg.forEach(function(msg){
        var Obj = {
           'sender': msg.sender,
           'message':msg.message
      }
      msgSender.push(Obj)
   })
   console.log(msgSender.sender)

  res.render('messages',{'sender': msgSender.sender, 'message': msgSender.message})
```

The main problem is if I put a for loop the render only loads the last message sent to the user. And also you can't set headers. I was thinking of doing a 
    `res.send{'sender': msgSender.sender, 'message': msgSender.message})`. Here is the handblebar code:

```
 <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Messages</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
     <h1>From: {{sender}}</h1>

    <h3><p>Message: {{message}}</p></h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So what is the problem? This didn't work?

Comment: @AkarshSatija No, it would just load an empty white page.

Comment: That means there's something wrong with the rendering or the data being passed.
Try printing just the output object instead of rendering template
    `res.json(msgSender)`

Comment: @AkarshSatija I don't think so I could pass one message perfectly fine, but I need to render the page and the message all at once. Once you send a res, you can't send more data, is the impression im getting.